# Using function to get variable name - returning variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you're tempted to say this has been answered by the SO answer: 5117127 please don't - it doesn't help me out. That answer says I can use the window object to access it: window['varToReturn'] - this is not working.

A basic form:

```
<form id="formID">
     <input type="number" id="inputID"/>
</form>
```

I have basic variables with values:

```
var varName1 = 1 ;
var varName2 = 2 ;
```

Then am using a function to get the appropriate variable name to return:

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputValue= $("#inputID").val();
            
            var varToReturn = 'varName' + inputValue;

            console.log(varToReturn);
    });
```

It's returning 'varToReturn1' - not the variable value (which is just '1')...am sure it's probably a simple thing, but help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you need is **one** variable, whose value is an **array**. Then all you need to do is index into the array with the input value.

Comment: I've tried that - but when I index into it it's returning the index of the array_name and not the value. Similar problem.

Comment: Why do you have varName1 and varName2 declared if you're not going to be using them?

Comment: I'm pulling the vars from a CSV file via PHP and tried an array - but had a similar problem with the array_name indexing the name itself and not the value - someone closed this saying it's been answered but the answer is not the answer...would like some help still.